how i can print or sum one larger hex in bash
when i use
printf "%064X\n" $((0x1a838b13505b26867))

the number one was truncated
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A838B13505B26867

with big hex/number is worse
printf "%064X\n" $((0x349b84b6431a6c4ef1))
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009B84B6431A6C4EF1

number has to be print accurate because i will sum them don't have to be printf
can be bc or other thing as long as i can put in bash script is fine
try
printf "%X\n" $((0x349b84b6431a6c4ef1 + 1))
9B84B6431A6C4EF2

expecting
printf "%X\n" $((0x349b84b6431a6c4ef1 + 1))
349B84B6431A6C4EF2


That number (the one in the example) requires 65bit to be represented, but bash doesn't manage such big numbers.  Only 64bit are allowed.

Using gnu awk you can handle this:
awk -M -v n='0x349b84b6431a6c4ef1' 'BEGIN {printf "%x\n", (strtonum(n) + 1)}'

349b84b6431a6c4ef2


Just be aware that this functionality may not be around much longer, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/MPFR-On-Parole.html.

NB: my ancient version of bc (macos bc 1.06 from 2000 !)
barfs at lowercase hex, hence the ${hexnumber^^} to uppercase ,
remove if not needed.
bignum=349b84b6431a6c4ef1
bc <<<"obase=16;ibase=16;${bignum^^}+1"
349B84B6431A6C4EF2


Lowercase letters are reserved for variable and function names, ^^ is needed everywhere.

i like the simplicit very good but i will accept the awk one just because i don't know adding leading zeros with bc

Printing it is easy - just treat it as a string.
$: printf "%064s\n" 1a838b13505b26867
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a838b13505b26867

But adding leading zeroes out to a 64-byte string has nothing to do with the numeric value.
Doing math with it is going to be problematic. bash doesn't handle numbers bigger than 2^63-1.
The biggest number my system will handle:
$: printf "%d\n" 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF # this it can manage
9223372036854775807
$: printf "%d\n" 0x8000000000000000 # this (2^63) chokes it
bash: printf: warning: 0x8000000000000000: Numerical result out of range
9223372036854775807

Go with bc or python or perl.
